# Python evaluate ifs before loop

Tags: python, loops, for-loop, if-statement, evaluate

```
def fun(x):
    for k in range(10):
        found = False
        if x < 12 and other(k):
            dostuff()
            found = True
        if x == 4 and other2(k):
            dostuff()
            found = True

        if not found:
            dootherstuff(k)
```

I have this code. My question is if these if statements can be evaluated beforehand since x does not change?

The code should do the same thing as:

```
 def fun(x):
    if x == 4:
        for k in range(10):
            if other2(k):
               dostuff()
            else:
               dootherstuff(k)

    if x < 12:
       for k in range(10):
            if other(k):
               dostuff()
            else:
               dootherstuff(k)
```

Or

```
def fun(x):
    for k in range(10):
        if x == 4 and other2(k) or x < 10 and other(k):
           dostuff()
         else:
           dootherstuff(k)
```

But since both of these are very un DRY and ugly I wonder if there is a better option. In my real code I have way more statements but all I need is for some values of X a specific check in the loop and I don't want to check X in every iteration since it does not change.

Answer (score 0):

Think this should work same:

```
 def fun(x):
    for k in range(10);
        if x < 12 and other(k):
           dostuff()
        elif x == 4 and other2(k):
           dostuff()
        else:
           dootherstuff(k)
```

Comment: yeah but you still evaluated x in every iteration which is the problem

Answer (score 0):

You can do the following

```
def fun(x):
    cond1 = x < 12
    cond2 = x == 4


    for k in range(10):
        found = False
        if cond1 and other(k):
            dostuff()
            found = True
        if cond2 and other2(k):
            dostuff()
            found = True

        if not found:
            dootherstuff(k)
```